# JavaScript loads but doesn't run - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress theme and can't get JavaScript to run. When I view the source code the scripts have loaded and the file paths are correct.

Here is the functions.php code that loads the scripts:

```
function theme_js() {
    // Conditional scripts
    global $wp_scripts;

    wp_register_script( 'html5_shiv', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js',
    '', '', false );
    wp_register_script( 'respond_js', 'https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js',
    '', '', false );

    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'html5_shiv', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');
    $wp_scripts->add_data( 'respond_js', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9');
    // Footer scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'color_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/jquery.color.js',
    array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'header_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/header.js',
    array('jquery'), null, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'rollover_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/rollover.js',
    array('jquery'), null, true );
}
add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );
```

Can anybody tell me why they won't run?

For reference - header.js:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

//After scrolling 300px from the top...
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 300) {
    $(".navbar").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "#1e3b4e"}, 600);
    $(".navbar-nav > li > a").css("color", "#ffffff");
    $("#logo").attr("src", "img/logo.png");

//Otherwise remove inline styles and thereby revert to original stying
} else {
    $(".navbar").stop().animate({backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 255, 1)"}, 400);
    $(".navbar-nav > li > a").css("color", "#1e3b4e");
    $("#logo").attr("src", "img/newlogo.png");
}
```

});

Comment: Wordpress doesn't run JavaScript. Your browser does. Check to make sure that the `<script>` tags are even in the source output.

Comment: The <script> tags are in the source code, and when clicked the JS source opens, but the browser doesn't run them.

Comment: Please correct the code `$wp_scripts-&gt;` if its typo. Also is your conditional scripts are also being rendered to the source?

Comment: If you are sure that all the scripts are rendered correctly to the html source (in footer), can you show us the contents of any script which being call on some action?

Comment: The scripts are only being called from the functions.php file. color_js is simply jquery-color. I'm no longer using rollover.js. header.js is now in the original post

Comment: They work when being linked on a static HMTL document